# Decompiling a .webpart file?

Tags: development, web-part, solution-package

I know it is possible to decompile SharePoint web parts if you have their .dll or .wsp files (I have successfully done this myself using tools like DotPeek or [this method](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/02/16/rebuilding-a-.wsp-file-in-4-easy-steps.aspx)), but what if you are left with just a ".webpart" file? Renaming it to a .zip doesn't work, and it's not a supported file type in a decompiler either. Is there any way to resurrect the source from these?

Comment: And, you don't really have to "decompile" wsp files. They're just cab files. Just add the .cab extension to the file name, and open with windows explorer.

Comment: I didn't specifically say I was "decompiling" .wsp, I linked to the method that will extract the files inside it. I said decompiling was for .dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.webpart` files are XML.

Open it with Notepad or your favorite XML editor.

See [Web Part Properties - part 3 - the .webpart file](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-3-the-webpart-file.aspx) by Wictor Wilen for an example.

Comment: And since its just an XML file that describes it, there is no actual code to review/change.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to see the contents now, but it doesn't really help me in actually modifying the web part itself. I guess I need to track down the .wsp or .dll.